# Transfer all msg.sender.balance to contract, without requiring user to input the msg.value?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

Is there a way to drain all the user.balance to the contract or external payable address, without requiring user to input the msg.value?

The most intuitive version I had looks a bit like this on solidity 0.5.0:

`address(this).transfer(msg.sender.balance)`

However it seems like contract address is inherently not payable, so I tried to first cast it into a payable address:

`address payable payableContract = address(uint160(address(this)))`

But it doesn’t seem to work either. Someone suggested me to look into Contract Factory which might solve the problem. What would be the best way to get around it, in order to achieve the same result?

Comment: A contract can't forcibly take a user's ether.

Comment: @smarx Is there a way for the user to pre-authorize the transaction?

Comment: The only way an externally owned account's balance can be transferred is if that account sends a transaction that does transfers that ether away.

Comment: @smarx Like a escrow contract?

Comment: Are you talking about Eth balance or ERC20 balance? I'll show you what you _can_do, but focusing on one or the other will simplify it.

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab Ideally for both, but transferring ether is more important to what I'm currently building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the flow of things or this will never make sense.

There is no way to code a contract to transfer funds from a user wallet. Not all, not some, not any.

> `address(this).transfer(msg.sender.balance)`

That means the destination (`to`) is `address(this)` and the amount is the `msg.sender`'s balance. `from: address` is *implicitly* `address(this)` because *nothing else is possible*. Therefore, `from` isn't mentioned in the syntax.

What you actually want to happen is for the *user* to sign a transaction that sends their money to your contract. I don't know why it has to be their entire balance and that sounds to me like another design misstep but here is how you would do it.

It's a front-end concern. Again, for emphasis, because only the user can authorize the transfer of their own funds. On the contract side, all you can do is receive it, validate the transaction and possibly reject it if something is wrong.

```
function depositFunds() public payable {
  // carry on
  // msg.value and msg.sender inform about who and how much
}
```

On the front end you would Web3 or a similar library to help the user form a valid transaction with `amount: as much as possible, to: your contract, {gas: amount, gasPrice: bid}`.

The user has to pay for gas, and this will reduce the amount of funds available to send to your contract. You have to take that into account. Your *front end* will have to figure out:

- gas estimate for the transaction
- gasPrice (Ether cost consumed = gas estimate * gasPrice)
- Funds available to send (user's balance - cost consumed), leaving the user with exactly 0 remaining balance.

If the browser (or server) performs the computation, then the user will be presented the option to sign a transaction sending x amount, and bidding y for gas, with a gas estimate of z leaving them with a final balance of `0`.

It's unclear to me why anyone would agree to such terms.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Rob, really appreciate your effort and time to answer this question. I enjoy your charity and details in the response. We want to build something that essentially requires Alice to pre-authorize a pending transaction that will send her entire balance to Bob on a future date. Therefore, one of the biggest design challenges is that we don't know what that future msg.balance will be, when certain conditions are met.

Comment: The simplest approach is to have Alice to place some funds in a contract that will only release to Bob. Bob would be able to see the funds are locked up for him. A lot depends on the real use case you have in mind.

Comment: Are there other approaches that can creatively get around it?

Comment: As asked, nothing obvious, but the way you describe "send full balance" does not seem reasonable to me. I think you might be imposing hidden assumptions into a use-case that should be approached another way. If you were my client, I would ask you what Alice and Bob need to know and do and keep asking until you explain it without telling me how you think it should be coded.

Comment: I might say ELIF, explain it like I'm an end user, explain it so my Mom can understand it.

Comment: Ah. One way to tackle that is a wallet contract (not EOA). Various parties in the contract have different privileges. The usual owner may be a single signer who can do the regular stuff. A quorum of trustees could possibly rule on a decision such as seizure. It's not a contract that tries to do impossible things to the wallet. It's a wallet that is implemented as a contract. Another way to tackle it is to use erasure encoding on the owner's private key so something like 2/3 fragments can reassemble it. Thanks for accepting my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: How do we use a wallet that is implemented as a contact? I like your suggestions by the way

Comment: We're going to be punished for being too chatty. It would make for a good new question. In essence, you make a contract does relays commands the contract owner sends it. You could explore multisig wallets for some ideas. It would potentially have an "owner" and a set of delegates who can vote to seize control via `transferOwnership()`. There are, of course, many details to think through so everything is agreed in advance. The owner would need to change delegates from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices you've provided so far. Been looking up multi-sig wallets for the past hour now. Ethereum community definitely needs more people like yourself. You are the man, Rob!